# How can I find the Start and End Dates under a Supervisor Code using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain the dates in which an employee is in a certain supervisor code. Some employees might have gaps in the their employment in which the switch from supervisor to non-supervisor. I am having trouble getting the date before the supervisor status changes (to capture the last date of a supervisor stint). Here is the table I am using.

| ID | Employee | Position_Title | Effective_Date | Supervisor_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-05 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-04 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-03 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-02 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-01 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2017-01-02 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2016-01-04 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2015-01-05 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2014-01-06 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2013-11-11 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2012-01-01 | Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2017-01-02 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2016-01-04 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2015-01-05 | Non-Supervisor |
| 1234 | John Adams | Staff | 2014-01-06 | Non-Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2018-01-02 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2016-02-11 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | President | 2015-09-03 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | Vice President | 2014-09-01 | Supervisor |
| 5678 | Stacy Jones | Staff | 2013-09-01 | Non-Supervisor |

Here is the output I am expecting:

| ID | Employee | Position_Title | Supervisor_Start | Supervisor_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Adams | President | 2020-01-01 |  |
| 1234 | John Adams | Vice President | 2012-01-01 | 2014-01-05 |
| 1234 | Stacy Jones | President | 2014-09-01 |  |

Here is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe from the given table
data = {'ID': [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678, 5678, 5678, 5678],
        'Employee': ['John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones'],
        'Position_Title': ['President', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Vice President', 'Vice President', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'Vice President', 'Staff'],
        'Effective_Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2016-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2013-11-11', '2012-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2016-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2018-01-02', '2016-02-11', '2015-09-03', '2014-09-01', '2013-09-01'],
        'Supervisor_Status': ['Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new dataframe with "Supervisor" instances
supervisors = df[df['Supervisor_Status'] == 'Supervisor']

# Create a new column with the start date of each "Supervisor" instance
supervisors['Start_Date'] = supervisors['Effective_Date']

# Create a new column with the end date of each "Supervisor" instance
supervisors['End_Date'] = supervisors['Effective_Date'].shift(-1)

# Group the "Supervisor" instances by Employee and Position_Title
grouped_supervisors = supervisors.groupby(['Employee', 'Position_Title'])

# Create a new dataframe with the start and end dates of each "Supervisor" instance
result = pd.DataFrame({'Supervisor_Start': grouped_supervisors['Start_Date'].first(), 'Supervisor_End': grouped_supervisors['End_Date'].last()})

# Reset the index of the dataframe
result = result.reset_index()
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: And what specific "trouble" are you having?

Answer (score 1):

I did it using a for loop, there is probably better ways to do it but i think this can help you:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe from the given table
data = {'ID': [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678, 5678, 5678, 5678],
        'Employee': ['John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'John Adams', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones', 'Stacy Jones'],
        'Position_Title': ['President', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Vice President', 'Vice President', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'Staff', 'President', 'President', 'President', 'Vice President', 'Staff'],
        'Effective_Date': ['2020-01-05', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2016-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2013-11-11', '2012-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2016-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2018-01-02', '2016-02-11', '2015-09-03', '2014-09-01', '2013-09-01'],
        'Supervisor_Status': ['Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Supervisor', 'Non-Supervisor']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
grouped_supervisors = df.groupby(['Employee', "Position_Title"])
output = [['ID', 'Employee', "Position_Title", "Supervisor_Start", "Supervisor_End"]]

for i in grouped_supervisors:
  if list(i[1]["Supervisor_Status"])[0] == "Supervisor":
    temp = (list(i[1].loc[:, ('ID', 'Employee', 'Position_Title', 'Effective_Date')].min()))
    temp.append(i[1]['Effective_Date'].max())
    output.append(temp)
    
headers = output.pop(0)
print(pd.DataFrame(output, columns=headers))
```

Output:

```
     ID     Employee  Position_Title Supervisor_Start Supervisor_End
0  1234   John Adams       President       2020-01-01     2020-01-05
1  1234   John Adams  Vice President       2012-01-01     2013-11-11
2  5678  Stacy Jones       President       2015-09-03     2018-01-02
3  5678  Stacy Jones  Vice President       2014-09-01     2014-09-01
```

Comment: Thanks for this attempt. The Supervisor_Start dates are almost correct but the Supervisor_End dates seem to be off. The expected output in my post is what I am hoping to get.